How to calculate this integral
Is there a formula of this integral
$$\int_{S_{2n-1}} \frac{e^{i a \langle z, \zeta \rangle}}{|z - \zeta|^{2\lambda}} \, d\sigma(\zeta)$$
and how to calculate it.
Thank you in advance

May I respectfully suggest a peruse of https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/ ?

Partial answer.
By rotational invariance, the integral depends only on $|\zeta|$. One may assume that $z$ is $re_1$ where $r \ge 0$ and $e_1$ is the first vector of the canonical basis. Then $\langle z, \zeta \rangle$ and $|z - \zeta|^2$ depends only on $\zeta_1$ (the first coordinate of $\zeta$). Applying Fubini theorem lead to an integral of the form
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^{i a r\zeta_1}}{(r^2 + 1 - 2r\zeta_1)^{\lambda}} \, c_n (1-\zeta_1^2)^{(n-1)/2}d\zeta_1.$$
